# How to save/load keras model with several branches

Tags: merge, save, keras

I define a keras (2.0.6) model with two branches the merge these

```
 left=Sequential()

  ...

  right=Sequential() 

  ...

  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Merge([left,right], mode='concat'))

 model.save('mymodel.model')
```

Then later if I want to reuse my model after `model = load('mymodel.model')` I am getting

```
"ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 5 layers into a model with 1 layers.".
```

So it seems the save command has only saved the 'model' part of my model, not the left and right branches. How can a save the entire model? Or will I need three model files, one for the left branch, one for the right and one for the merged model?

Seems there has been a discussion on this previously (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1349) but there was no solution, as far as I can see.

Does anyone know whether/how this has been solved?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the Sequential API for this, prefer the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to build such a model with branches. Then you will only have a single model and it will be saved as such.